# "lost" main & secondary menu (drupal)

Tags: drupal, menu

I have stupidly unticked both the main and secondary menu in the Bootstrap settings options (too many windows open!). I have lost both the Drupal and Civi menus and basically all administrator ability to access/edit anything via the frontend.. :(

I can get back to the Bootstrap settings page via the browser back button but now just get and now get "access denied" if i try to re-enable the menus. Any pointers where to go on the backend to restore? Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's possible it's just your login session got ended, so if you haven't already tried I'd try just logging in again.

Otherwise there might also be more going on that's not related to the main/secondary menu because it looks like you have something customized, but you can try this directly in the database to reset. Assuming drupal 7.

`update variable SET value = 'a:15:{s:11:"toggle_logo";i:1;s:11:"toggle_name";i:1;s:13:"toggle_slogan";i:1;s:24:"toggle_node_user_picture";i:1;s:27:"toggle_comment_user_picture";i:1;s:32:"toggle_comment_user_verification";i:1;s:14:"toggle_favicon";i:1;s:16:"toggle_main_menu";i:1;s:21:"toggle_secondary_menu";i:1;s:12:"default_logo";i:1;s:9:"logo_path";s:0:"";s:11:"logo_upload";s:0:"";s:15:"default_favicon";i:1;s:12:"favicon_path";s:0:"";s:14:"favicon_upload";s:0:"";}' where name='theme_seven_settings';`

You might have a custom theme so the `name=` part might need adjusting. You can do

`SELECT * FROM variable WHERE name like '%_settings';` to see what you have.

Comment: Yes! my clean up of navigation menus meant i had also lost my login page... going direct to the url login sorted it :)